# CodeIgniter equivalent code for SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have this query and I want to put it on my code igniter php.

`SELECT MAX(IDnumber) FROM student WHERE IDnumber LIKE '2013256%'`

I trued this one but it returns error:

```
$this->db->select_max('IDnumber');
$this->db->get('student');
$IDnumber = $this->db->like('IDnumber', '2013256', 'after'); 
return $IDnumber;
```

does anyone have an idea about my case? thanks in advance...

Comment: is this a typo `$this->db-select_max` ? should't it be `$this->db->select_max` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting result after `$this->db->get()`, so use

```
$this->db->select_max('IDnumber');
$this->db->like('IDnumber', '2013256', 'after'); 
$this->db->from('student');
return $this->db->get();
```

Also You can use chaining method:

```
return $this->db->select_max('IDnumber')->like('IDnumber', '2013256', 'after')->get('student');
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's intended to be used as a "fluent interface" as well, so you could drop the repeated $this->db and chain everything together: `$this->db->select_max()->from()->where()` etc

Comment: @IMSoP edited my answer before Your comment ;) Anyway sometimes it more useful to split chains into lines (for studying someone, for example)

Comment: True. I was actually surprised it was $this->db being chained, and not a separate object representing the particular query. Not how I'd have built it, but then little of CodeIgniter is ;)